# How do I execute a ruby command (such as to execute a ruby script) from within the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From within the Rails console, I would like to execute a ruby script, e.g. setup_for_experimenting.rb, that creates objects for and then executes the ruby program that I want to experiment with. The program I'm experimenting with is a service that is not yet completely written and has no tests yet, either, but I can execute it from within rails console.

How do I do give the command `ruby setup_for_experimenting.rb` from within the rails console?

Comment: Did try to run that command in console? `ruby setup_for_experimenting.rb`

Comment: you can require script in rails console and then use it

Comment: I did the require (as suggested by the accepted answer below), but it executed immediately (which is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any plain ruby file inside the console with require

So in your case inside hte console

```
require "./setup_for_experimenting.rb"
```